# Split Number in SQL Server by backslash

Tags: sql-server

How to Split a number like 10000 in sql server with / after 3 numbers.

So the output should be like

```
 `100/00`
```

Comment: That's a forward slash - not a backslash ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query below. It checks if you have at least 3 digits to return the split number or otherwise returns the number as it is (feel free to tweak it).

```
declare @number as int = 1000
select case
    when LEN(cast(@number as varchar(100))) > 3 then SUBSTRING(cast(@number as varchar(100)), 1, 3) + '/' + SUBSTRING(cast(@number as varchar(100)), 4, LEN(cast(@number as varchar(100))) - 3)
    else cast(@number as varchar(100))
end
```

Comment: How about using STUFF(@Number, 3,0, '/') for this?

Comment: Even nicer tough it should be `select STUFF(@Number, 4,0, '/')`

Answer (score 0):

It will still require CASE as follows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN (@number) > 3 THEN STUFF(@number, 4, 0, '/') ELSE CONVERT (VARCHAR, @number) END;
```

otherwise it will return NULL with LEN (@number) <= 3.
By the way, it is a slash not a backslash.